# Prove that a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is measureable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is measureable.

Theorem: A function $:\mathbb{R}\to [-\infty,\infty]$ is measurable if and only if $f^-1(E)\in \mathcal{M}$ for every $E\in\mathcal{B}$.

How do I use the fact that f is continuous to show that it is measurable?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, what can I say about $f^{-1}(U)$ if $U$ is open? Moreover, make use of the fact that the open sets generate the Borel sigma algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set ${\cal A}=\{E \in {\cal B}: f^{-1}(E)\in {\cal M}\}$. 
   This is a $\sigma$-algebra (why ?)
2. If $f$ is continuous, ${\cal A}$ contains all open sets.
3. ${\cal B}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open sets.
4. Therefore if $f$ is continuous, ${\cal A} ={\cal B}$.

Note: the very same argument shows that if ${\cal A}$ contains a subset generating ${\cal B}$ (e.g. subbasis for the topology, one-sided infinite intervals in ${\mathbb R}$, etc.), then $f$ is measurable. Continuity is a lot to ask...